Is it possible to convert gltf to byte array and then convert byte array back into a file?
I im trying to store GLTF file in a postgreSQL. I came up with an idea to convert file to byte array with memory Stream. But when i try to convert it back, from byte array to file with System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes i get damaged file.
Is it possible to convert gltf to bytes and then back again?
I was trying to use packages like SharpGLTF, but it does not help.

I would suggest to read the file, Base64-encode it and then store into the database as text. Read in the opposite order.

The trouble was that GLTF2.0 is encoded type of file. Converting it to array crashes its content. The only solution i found was using .obj or .fbx formats.

The basic approach to save or retrieve a file from the database is:
Read the raw file into a byte[] array.
Save that byte[] array into the database.
And to retrieve the file?
Then get/load/query the database row.
Cast the binary column into a byte[] array.
Save/write the byte array to a file.
So, code to save a file into database will look like this:
(I'm using SQL server, not PostgreSQL, but the code should be near identical using the PostgreSQL .net database provider).
So, to save a file to the database, then this:
        string sFile = Server.MapPath($@"~/UpLoadFiles/control.pdf");
        byte[] FileAsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(sFile); 

        string sFileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(sFile);

        string strSQL =
            @"INSERT INTO tblFiles (FileName, UpLoaded, MineType, FileB)
            VALUES (@FileName, @UpLoaded, @MineType, @FileB)";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sFileNameOnly;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@UpLoaded", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@MineType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
            MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(sFile);
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@FileB", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = FileAsBytes;

        General.MyRstE(cmdSQL);

And to do the reverse, and get a file from the database, then this:
        int PK = 3;  // for testing database PK row id

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblFiles WHERE ID = @ID");
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PK;

        DataTable dt = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);

        string strFile = dt.Rows[0]["FileName"].ToString();

        byte[] FileAsBytes = dt.Rows[0]["FileB"] as byte[]; 

        File.WriteAllBytes(strFile, FileAsBytes);   

I don't know what column types are available in PostgreSQL, but a binary or blob type of column should exist, and using such a column type should allow the above process of converting a file to a byte[] array, and then sending that to the database.
And as the above shows, you reverse the process when wanting to get a valid file from the database. So, get the row you need, convert the blob/binary column to a byte array, and then save that byte array to a file.
Since we using a byte array, then the file type being text, pdf, a .dll, or whatever does not matter.
And I used in above some handy helper routines, since I don't want to type over and over creating the database connection object, and command object.
So, the helper routines used above from my global static class was:
    public static DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }


    public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }


    public static void MyRstE(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }


Sure,  but then again the posted code will work with any file type and thus no limitations exists with above code.  Minor advantages exists here,  but Sure, using a string in place of a byte[] array still a good suggestion on your part
